# T-SQL - how to insert while looping through a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that holds organization data. I also have a new table that is going to hold info about shipping containers. 
As an initial test I want to populate the new Shipping_Containers table by giving one container to each organization. 
So I thought about getting the organization ids and looping through them and doing an insert into Shipping_Containers for each organization id, something like this:

```
select * into #orgs from Organization_1
while (select id from #orgs ) IS NOT NULL
begin
    insert into Shipping_Containers (name, org) 
    values('test_name', id)
end
```

I know there is probably a lot wrong with that but firstly it is giving this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'id'.
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm new to T-SQL so any guidance here would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does Organization_1 have a column called id? Also if you want to loop through the records (no need to in this instance) then you need to use a cursor. MSDN can help you out with cursors (again there is no need for a cursor in this instance)

Comment: Yes, Organization_1 does have an id column. I'll read up cursors too, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
INSERT INTO Shipping_Containers (name, org)
SELECT 'test_name', id
  FROM Organization_1
```